# How to wait for enclosed asynchronous block to finish

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

I'm having an issue with `stream().forEach` it doesn't finish in time before the method returns, here's how :

My entity :

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Foo {
    private String a;
    private int b;
    private int c;
    private String d;
    private String e;
}
```

I have a method that calls an external service that gets a list of `Foo` and then for each member of that list it calls two other external services to fill `d` and  `e` fields :

```java
public List<Foo> getOrdresListe() {
    Foo[] fooArray = externalServiceOne.getFooList();
    Arrays.stream(fooArray).forEach((f) -> {
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(AsyncUtils.supplierWithCustomDependencies(() -> {
            Dob dob = externalServiceTwo.getDeeEntity(f.getA());
            f.setD(dob.getD());
            Efo efo = externalServiceThree.getEeeEntity(f.getA());
            f.setE(efo.getE());
            return f;
        }));
    });
    List<Foo> fooList = Arrays.asList(fooArray);
    return fooList; // when this statement is reached d and e fields are null.
}
```

Because of some performance issues (and some best practices) I'm calling `externalServiceTwo.getDeeEntity` and `externalServiceThree.getEeeEntity` asynchronously with a custom supplier to embark some dependencies when invoking the services. But the main issue is that when returning `fooList` `d` and `e` fields are null.

My question is how to wait for all async executions fo finish before returning `fooList` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just remember the async tasks and wait for their completion manually:

```java
public List<Foo> getOrdresListe() {
    Foo[] fooArray = externalServiceOne.getFooList();

    final List<CompletableFuture<Foo>> futures = new ArrayList<>(); // remember each

    Arrays.stream(fooArray).forEach((f) -> {
        futures.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                AsyncUtils.supplierWithCustomDependencies(() -> {
            Dob dob = externalServiceTwo.getDeeEntity(f.getA());
            f.setD(dob.getD());
            Efo efo = externalServiceThree.getEeeEntity(f.getA());
            f.setE(efo.getE());
            return f;
        })));
    });

    for (CompletableFuture<Foo> future : futures) {
        future.join(); // wait for each
    }

    List<Foo> fooList = Arrays.asList(fooArray);
    return fooList;
}
```

Comment: This works but performance wise it takes too much time !

Comment: @Fourat Your question is *"... how to wait for all async executions fo finish ..."* and that's exactly what my answer does. If it takes too long, it's because your async tasks take much time.

Comment: you're right but your answer is equivalent to running the whole thing without async and futures. Is there any other way to make it faster ?

Comment: @Fourat This is wrong, it's not equivalent. Where do you get this conclusion from? All tasks *are* running async here. Please check out a [Guide To CompletableFuture](https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture) or any other documentation/tutorial.

Comment: I know, but when I logger the current thread name it shows always the same thread `logger.info("Foo : " + f.getA() + " Current Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());` I guess that's why it takes so much time !

Comment: @Fourat This is indeed strange. It should not be always the same thread. There is `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` behind default `CompletableFuture`, which should utilize multiple threads. Could you check your environment, e.g. `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`, what `AsyncUtils` maybe does additionally, trying out with custom `ForkJoinPool` etc.?

Comment: I fixed it, it was a `stream().forEach` issue. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create all `CompletableFuture`s as an intermediate operation and wait for all async executions to finish in the terminal operation.

```
Arrays.stream(fooArray).map((f) -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(AsyncUtils.supplierWithCustomDependencies(() -> {
                Dob dob = externalServiceTwo.getDeeEntity(f.getA());
                f.setD(dob.getD());
                Efo efo = externalServiceThree.getEeeEntity(f.getA());
                f.setE(efo.getE());
                return f;
            })
    )).forEach(fooCompletableFuture -> {
        try {
            fooCompletableFuture.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This works but performance wise it takes too much time !

Comment: Well, you will somehow have to wait for all the executions to finish.

Answer (score 1):

May be try something like this: Send the request Async and create the List of Completable Futures of type `Foo` and then using `join` as a terminal operation as @boobalan suggested; you get the results in this way  you can wait for all async executions fo finish before returning fooList.

```
List<foo> fooData = externalServiceOne.getFooList();

//Sends the request asynchronously and returns the Completable Future of type Foo which can be later used to get the results using `get` or `join`
private List<CompletableFuture<Foo>> sendRequest() {
    return fooData.stream().map(this::computeAsync).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private CompletableFuture<Foo> computeAsync(Foo f) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(AsyncUtils.supplierWithCustomDependencies(() -> {
                Dob dob = externalServiceTwo.getDeeEntity(f.getA());
                f.setD(dob.getD());
                Efo efo = externalServiceThree.getEeeEntity(f.getA());
                f.setE(efo.getE());
                return f 
           });

private List<Foo> processResponse() {
   List<CompletableFuture<Foo>> futureResult = sendRequest();

   List<Foo> fooList = futureResult.stream()
            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
     return fooList;
    }

}
```